# Is it possible to use a loc inside a loc in Pandas to replace a value?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, valueerror, pandas-loc

Let me first sketch the problem I am trying to solve. I am trying to replace a value '-1' with another value in the same column, based on two other values in the row containing the '-1'. To be more clear, here is an example. In the dataframe underneath, there are two missing values in the 'owner' column. What I want is to replace each '-1' value with a value in the 'owner' column that has the same 'price' value and which is the first one that occurs earlier in 'time' than the '-1' value. So, in this example, the first `-1` value is found in line 3. The corresponding 'price' and 'time' is `cheap` and `2011-01-01 13:30:00`. So now, I would like to replace the `-1` with the name of the owner, that has a `cheap`car, which is the first in time before the one under consideration, so the first time before `2011-01-01 13:30:00`. In this case, that would be the one in line 1, with owner name `Jane`. This should also automatically be done for any following `-1` values (e.g. for the Bmw).

```
   brand   price time                 owner
0   Honda  cheap 2008-01-01 13:30:00  Marc
1  Toyota  cheap 2009-01-01 13:30:00  Jane
2    Ford   alot 2010-01-01 13:30:00  Phil
3    Audi  cheap 2011-01-01 13:30:00    -1
4   Volvo  cheap 2012-01-01 13:30:00  Jane
5     Bmw   alot 2013-01-01 13:30:00    -1
```

The way I wanted to solve this problem, was by first locating the -1, then saving the corresponding price and time and then locating the first corresponding price in time and replace the owner value. I wanted to use the Pandas Loc method for this in the following way (I included the code to make the dataframe as well).

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

cars = {'brand': ['Honda','Toyota','Ford','Audi','Volvo','Bmw'],
        'price': ['cheap','cheap','alot','cheap','cheap','alot'],
        'time': [datetime.strptime('1/1/2008 1:30 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('1/1/2009 1:30 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('1/1/2010 1:30 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('1/1/2011 1:30 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'),
                 datetime.strptime('1/1/2012 1:30 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('1/1/2013 1:30 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')],
        'owner': ['Marc', 'Jane','Phil','-1','Jane','-1']}

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['brand', 'price','time','owner'])

P_T = df.loc[df.owner == '-1',['price','time']

df.loc[df.owner == '-1', 'owner'] = df.loc[(df.price == P_T.price)&(df.time < P_T.time), 'owner']
```

As you can see in the final line, this is essentially a loc within a loc, whereas the conditions on the right hand side of the equation are both based on the P_T loc. However, here comes the problem, as I keep getting this error:
`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`
I think I am doing something wrong and maybe doing things not as efficient as possible... So I would really appreciate some help with this matter.

Comment: the indexes of df and P_T are not the same, hence the value_error. you could possibly use ```reindex`` to make the same. but i'm not sure that is what u want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've over complicated this - what essentially you need to do is fill `-1` values with the last corresenponding value grouped by the price column? if so a forward fill will do `ffill`

```
import numpy as np
s = df.replace('-1',np.nan).sort_values('time').groupby(['price'])['owner'].ffill()

df['owner'] = df.index.map(s)



print(df)


    brand  price                time owner
0   Honda  cheap 2008-01-01 13:30:00  Marc
1  Toyota  cheap 2009-01-01 13:30:00  Jane
2    Ford   alot 2010-01-01 13:30:00  Phil
3    Audi  cheap 2011-01-01 13:30:00  Jane
4   Volvo  cheap 2012-01-01 13:30:00  Jane
5     Bmw   alot 2013-01-01 13:30:00  Phil
```

Comment: Indeed.. I'm not as experienced with pandas, so I did not know about ffill. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RikHendrickx no problem my man, I've slightly edited the answer to keep your original index